# Client + Server based on micropython

Tags: python, python-requests, esp32, micropython

I know that here is more questions about micropython and requests, but after a lot of tries i don't know how to prepare client + server model.

Description of my situation:
I have two ESP32 devices (both with version):

```py
Entering REPL. Use Control-X to exit.
MicroPython v1.20.0 on 2023-04-26; ESP32 module with ESP32
```

#### Server Side (micropython)

(based on: https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-esp8266-micropython-web-server/)

```py
import network
import ujson
import usocket as socket
from machine import reset

nic = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
nic.active(True)
nic.connect('xxxxx', 'xxxxx')

# nic.ifconfig()
# ('192.168.1.155', '255.255.255.0', '192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2')

def server_response():
    response = ({"server_status": "OK",
                "temperature": "55.3"})
    return ujson.dumps(response)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('', 64664))
s.listen(5)

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    request = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    data = ujson.loads(request.split('\r\n\r\n'))
    print('>>', conn, addr)
    print('>>', data)

    response = server_response()
    conn.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n')
    conn.send('content-type: application/json\n')
    conn.send('Connection: close\n\n')
    conn.sendall(response)
    conn.close()
```

When i call server from "normal" python from iPython with code:

```py
import requests
import json

request_url = "http://192.168.1.155:64664/"
data = {"status":"on", "device": "thermometer"}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

print(requests.post(request_url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers).content)
# Response: b'{"temperature": "55.3", "server_status": "OK"}'
```

response is correct: `b'{"temperature": "55.3", "server_status": "OK"}`

But when i trying similar request from micropython client, still i have error messages...

### Client side (micropython)

```py
import ujson as json
import urequests as requests
import network
from machine import reset

nic = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
nic.active(True)
nic.connect('xxxxx', 'xxxxx')

# nic.ifconfig()
# ('192.168.1.135', '255.255.255.0', '192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2')

request_url = "http://192.168.1.155:64664/"
data = {"status":"on", "device": "thermometer"}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

r = requests.post(request_url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

Response:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "urequests.py", line 184, in post
  File "urequests.py", line 152, in request
ValueError: need more than 1 values to unpack
```

and i don't have idea, where is a problem.

During my research I tried a lot of code combination but still i don't have clear result :/
Please, what is a correct way for clear client + server model?